# Line rotation following user touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have had trouble figuring out how I should go about creating a line that originates from point A and points toward point B (User's finger) and beyond. Such a line might look like

(A) origin (B) finger

A-------B-----------

this line would reach off of the screen and should rotate when the user moves their finger. The code to create the line and move it's B coordinate in real time would also help. Thank you!

EDIT - What I've done so far:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
     let testball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
     let testguy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
     let line = SKShapeNode()
     let pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    testball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.addChild(testball)

    self.testguy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + testguy.frame.width + 10, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + testguy.frame.height + 10)
    self.testguy.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    self.addChild(self.testguy)

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, testguy.position.x, testguy.position.y)
    self.addChild(self.line)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    testball.position = (touches.first?.locationInNode(self))!

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).x)!, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y)!)
    self.line.path = pathToDraw
    self.line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    testball.position = (touches.first?.locationInNode(self))!
    //print(touches.first?.locationInView(self.view), appendNewline: true);

    line.removeFromParent()

    testball.position = (touches.first?.locationInNode(self))!

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).x)!, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y)!)
    self.line.path = pathToDraw
    self.line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.addChild(line)
}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt? Most people here like to see some of your code first.

Comment: @Caleb Totally forgot, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! All I had to do was change the code in `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` to

```
    line.removeFromParent()

    testball.position = (touches.first?.locationInNode(self))!

    let pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, testguy.position.x, testguy.position.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).x)!, (touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y)!)

    self.line.path = pathToDraw
    self.line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.addChild(self.line)
```

Inside `touchesEnded` I wrote `self.line.removeFromParent()` to delete the line once the user touched off the screen.